# bind parameter in whereraw query with join in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

below is my code to join two tables and get the latest messages of a particular user_id but i am not able to pass parameter into whereRaw clause. i have tried several ways but no outcome.

```
$id = $request->user_id;

$chats = DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('messages', function($query)
    {
        $query->on('users.id', '=', 'messages.to_id')
        ->whereRaw('messages.id IN (select MAX(messages.id) from messages join users on users.id = messages.to_id where messages.to_id = ? group by users.id)',[$id]);
    })
    ->select('users.id as user_id', 'users.name', DB::raw('CONCAT("https://www.interwebs.co.in/puzzle/attach/", users.avatar) AS image') , 'users.mobile', 'messages.id', 'messages.from_id', 'messages.to_id', 'messages.body as message', 'messages.attachment', 'messages.seen as seen_count', 'messages.created_at')
    ->where('messages.from_id', $request->user_id)
    ->orWhere('messages.to_id', $request->user_id)
    ->get();
```

it is just showing me the same error every time that undefined variable $id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$id` variable is out of scope when inside the callback passed to the `leftJoin` method.

To inherit `$id` from the parent scope, `use` it when passing the callback.

```php
$id = $request->user_id;

DB::table('users')->leftJoin('messages', function($query) use ($id) {
    // $id is now available here
});
```

Comment: thanks it really helped me a lot